# Custom SQL query ORDER BY term_order

Tags: wpdb, sql

I have custom taxonomy that list terms under "series" that contain posts that are also present in terms under "media_type" and where media_type is term_id 16.

I want to order the list by the term_order column in the terms table but it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
    $q_result = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT {$wpdb->terms}.name FROM {$wpdb->terms}
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} ON {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id = {$wpdb->terms}.term_id
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_taxonomy_id = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id
            WHERE {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy = 'series' AND {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id IN (
            SELECT object_id FROM {$wpdb->term_relationships}
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} ON {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_taxonomy_id = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id
            WHERE {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy = 'media_type' AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id = '16'
            ORDER BY {$wpdb->terms}.term_order
);");
```

Comment: This is an SQL question.

Comment: Does in not belong here?

Comment: You might get a better repsonse on stackoverflow.com

Comment: in this table `{$wpdb->terms}` do you have the `term_order` coloumn ??

Comment: This is clearly off-topic, despite the flag being rejected.  It is an SQL question, that is (to quote FAQ) _not specific to WordPress (even if they happen in its context)_

Comment: Sorry about the off topic. Should I delete this post?

Comment: Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

In your case   you are referring `ORDER BY {$wpdb->terms}.term_order` and as default in `wordpress`  `wp_terms` table don't have this column the `term_order` column resides in the `wp_term_relationships` table and you are referring `wp_terms` table to `ORDER BY` this column which is not is present in that table instead of this you have to do something like this

```
$q_result = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT {$wpdb->terms}.name FROM {$wpdb->terms}
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} ON {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id = {$wpdb->terms}.term_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_taxonomy_id = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id
        WHERE {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy = 'series' AND {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id IN (
        SELECT object_id FROM {$wpdb->term_relationships}
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} ON {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_taxonomy_id = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id
        WHERE {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy = 'media_type' AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id = '16'
        ORDER BY {$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_order ASC
)");
```

Comment: I went into phpMyAdmin and the wp_terms table has a column called term_order. I'm using a plugin the assign the numbers to the terms.